# Mongodb: $pull operator is not removing given value from array

Tags: mongodb, database

## edit:

Structure of document:

```
{"tags" : ["a"], "name" : "a", "creator" : "Nick here", "users" : [ "Nick here"], "connected" : 1, "ra" : 0.3967885102611035, "_id" : ObjectId("513c3e42071a103c09000003")}
```

---

I have problem with MongoDB $pull operator. It doesn't remove value from an array.
Here's my query:

```
db.rooms.update({users: ["Nick here"]},{$pull: {users: ["Nick here"]}})
```

Here's how users field looks like:

(...)`,"users" : [ "Nick here" ],`(...)

---

if I write it like this:

`db.rooms.update({users: "Nick here"},{$pull: {users: ["Nick here"]}})`

or

`db.rooms.update({users: "Nick here"},{$pull: {users: "Nick here"}})`

an error is returned:

> Cannot apply $pull/$pullAll modifier to non-array

---

What is wrong in those queries?
I want to pull/push users' nicks and remove document when 'users' field is empty.

Thanks in advance,
Michał

Comment: Can you show the structure of the document? There is nothing wrong with this query `db.rooms.update({users: "Nick here"},{$pull: {users: "Nick here"}})`

Comment: I've added document's structure

edit: it seems that nick is being pulled properly now, I don't know what was wrong with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote test… Check you syntax. Query:

```
db.rooms.update({'users': 'Nick here'}, {$pull: {'users': 'Nick here'}})
```

May be in your query need use `{ multi: true }`. For example:

```
db.rooms.update({'users': 'Nick here'}, {$pull: {'users': 'Nick here'}}, { multi: true })
```

Full log:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.3
connecting to: so
> db.rooms.insert({"tags" : ["a"], "name" : "a", "creator" : "Nick here", "users" : [ "Nick here"], "connected" : 1, "ra" : 0.3967885102611035, "_id" : ObjectId("513c3e42071a103c09000003")} )
> db.rooms.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("513c3e42071a103c09000003"),
    "tags" : [
        "a"
    ],
    "name" : "a",
    "creator" : "Nick here",
    "users" : [
        "Nick here"
    ],
    "connected" : 1,
    "ra" : 0.3967885102611035
}
> db.rooms.update({'users': 'Nick here'}, {$pull: {'users': 'Nick here'}})
> db.rooms.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("513c3e42071a103c09000003"),
    "connected" : 1,
    "creator" : "Nick here",
    "name" : "a",
    "ra" : 0.3967885102611035,
    "tags" : [
        "a"
    ],
    "users" : [ ]
}
>
```

Comment: That was not syntax problem.
I just changed 'users' structure from single value field to array and forgot to remove documents from earlier tests with non-array here. Thanks anyway for your time!